# Как вывести Адрес по клику на пин (Google maps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api

Есть карта с кастомным оформлением. Картинка пина тоже добавлена своя. Нужно сделать так, чтобы по клику на этот пин появлялся адрес. Как это реализовать?
[Смотреть код](https://jsfiddle.net/wmdohod/kfff1fmg/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var latitude = 32.764916,
    longitude = -97.048840,
    map_zoom = 18;


var marker_url = 'wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/img/icon-location.png';


var style= [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":35},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":"50"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"40"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]}]

var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: map_zoom,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: style
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-container'), map_options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    icon: marker_url,
});


function CustomZoomControl(controlDiv, map) { 
    var controlUIzoomIn= document.getElementById('zoom-in'),
        controlUIzoomOut= document.getElementById('zoom-out');
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomIn);
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomOut);


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomIn, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1)
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomOut, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)
    });
}

var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var zoomControl = new CustomZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);


map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(zoomControlDiv);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение данного вопроса тут https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Нужно было добавить к моему коду:

```
 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  'content'+
  '</div>'; 
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString}); 
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker); });
```